# Multi processing computing not working with jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am using a base 3.11.5 kernel from anaconda

[image: screenshot]

This code runs indefinitely inside my jupyter notebook (though it runs perfectly from a simple python file)

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
def sq(x):
    return x*x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(sq, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```